# change hyperlink trigger to double click for one program only (using AutoHotKey?)

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I'm willing to use any tools to do this, it's for a PDF program, I accidently click on hyperlinks once in a while which is infuriating

I tried using Windows built in functionality, googling and asking the magic conch (ChatGPT) who said AutoHotKey might help me but couldn't further produce anything useful, which is why I ask my question here on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

This works for Microsoft Edge:

```
#If MouseIsOver("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1") && (A_Cursor = "Unknown") ; Hand 

    LButton::
        If (A_PriorHotkey = A_ThisHotkey && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey <= DllCall("GetDoubleClickTime")) 
            Click
    return

#If

MouseIsOver(WinTitle){
    MouseGetPos,,, Win
        return WinExist(WinTitle . " ahk_id " . Win)
}
```

Use the [Window Spy](https://amourspirit.github.io/AutoHotkey-Snippit/WindowSpy.html) tool to get the ahk_class of your PDF program and replace `Chrome_WidgetWin_1` by that in the above code.

Comment: I get HwndWrapper[program.exe;;<someGUID>] as ahk_class. Can I use the ahk_exe somehow instead?

Comment: Try replacing `ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1` by `ahk_exe your_program.exe` as shown in Window Spy.